# Bigquery DML - SQL Output

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there an equivalent to ROWS INSERTED/ROWS DELETED at the end of a DML table load (insert/update/delete/merge) to audit a specific load?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the system variable named "@@row_count" will give you information about the number of modified rows. Here is the [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#system_variables) to a list of system variables.  It is a description of this variable copied from the documentation:

> If used in a script and the previous script statement is DML, specifies the number of rows modified, inserted, or deleted, as a result of that DML statement. If the previous statement is a MERGE statement, @@row_count represents the combined total number of rows inserted, removed, and deleted. This value is NULL if not in a script.

There is also a possibility to get the number of affected rows from the REST API response.

Here is the [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#response-body) to the documentation of the response body for the "jobs.query" resource in BigQuery API. You can find the attribute "numDmlAffectedRows," which gives you the information you need.